# Alignment goes wierd when exporting to excel in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm a newbie to SSRS and there are alot of things that i am unsure.
I've created some reports using SSDT tools. Everything is fine until I try to export to Excel and Word format. In PDF and Tiff type, it works ok. The table inside the reports retains the same
alignments, however, the other contents such as textboxes,rectangles change their position automatically. Does it usually occurs or is there any workaround or way that I need to be aware or correct when exporting my rdl files to excel and word format.

P.S: I haven't publish my files in IIS yet.

Someone please shed a light on this issue.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: If you have heading textboxes etc above the table data then you need to ensure that these line up with the data columns otherwise (for example) extra columns are created in Excel. Use the column widths of data columns to determine the possible widths of the heading text boxes e.g. data column 1 is 4.5 cm wide, data column 2 is 3.5 cm wide. A text box above this must therefore be 8cm wide to match widths

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34645127/2635532

Comment: To summarize the previous couple of comments: SSRS uses columns and rows in Excel to try and exactly reproduce the layout of your report design. Therefore if you have textboxes, tables etc. that are not *exactly* aligned in the report then SSRS will add columns or rows to try and space them out to the same layout in Excel. However this often leads to minor formatting issues, so the best approach is to design the report for Excel output by making sure that report items are aligned horizontally and vertically as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks you so much all. I will bear in mind these concepts whenever I design SSRS report. I've been scratching my head how to solve this issue and you all shed a light on it.